# Jquery callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I've got a line of code that looks like this where the callback never gets executed:

```
        GroupRepository.Add("#divSortingArea", oGroup, oSow.AddGroupToPage, (function() { alert(123); }));
```

Thks guys, no alert popup !

Cheers,
Shotemba

here is the full code:

function GroupRepository() {
}

GroupRepository.Add = function(targetSelection, oGroup, addToPage) {

```
var tableToInsert = null;

var nGroupID = oGroup.nScopeOfWorkGroupID;
var sDescription = oGroup.sScopeOfWorkGroupDescription;


Eclipse3.GroupService.InsertGroup(Globals.N_JOB_ID, oGroup, InsertGroup_Success, InsertGroup_Error);

function InsertGroup_Success(response) {
    nGroupID = parseInt(response.nIdentity);
    var bConcurrencyId = response.bNewConcurrencyId;

    //If this entry contains rows pull those rows out,
    var rows = tableToInsert.find("tbody tr");
    tableToInsert.remove();

    oGroup.nScopeOfWorkGroupID = nGroupID;
    oGroup.bConcurrencyId = bConcurrencyId;

    var newGroupElement = addToPage(oGroup);

    //add to the new group being created,
    newGroupElement.find("tbody").append(rows);


    //Globals.DisplayMessage("Insert Succeeded", "Your attempt to add a new record was successful.");
    Globals.DisplayMessage("Insert Group Succeeded", "A new record was added.");

    return this;
};

function InsertGroup_Error(error) {

    Globals.HandleError("Item Group Failed", error);
};
```

}

Comment: What is "GroupRepository" ? Please, give us more code. Alternately you can aslo http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: But what is this GroupRepository?

Comment: Thks for getting back @vinothkr, here is the full code, sorry about that :

Answer (score 0):

In your GroupRepository.Add there's only 3 parameters, targetSelection, oGroup and addToPage. To extend the callback, declare a new function:

```
function newCallBack(param) {
   var result = oSow.AddGroupToPage(param);
   alert(123);
   return(result);
}
```

and then:

```
GroupRepository.Add("#divSortingArea", oGroup, newCallBack);
```

Comment: Hi @ariel, I'd like function() { alert(123); } to be executed after oSow.AddGroupToPage has been called, earlier I had added a placehoder for function() { alert(123); } inside GroupRepository.Add("#divSortingArea", oGroup, oSow.AddGroupToPage,fn); but that didn't work either.

Comment: edited... you need to create a new function with both commands

Comment: hi @arial, or is there a simpler way, I just need to return nGroupID = parseInt(response.nIdentity) from InsertGroup_Success handler back to the caller.

Comment: no, this is the only way. You can't pass 2 callbacks in 1 parameter.

Comment: ic, thks @ariel, will take it for a spin and see how i go.

Comment: any luck on that? please accept the answer if this helped you